# How to create a new user with django rest framework and custom user model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users

I have a custom user model and I am using django-rest-framework to create API

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=254,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile', 'password1', 'password2')
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def create_user(request):
    serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        User.objects.create_user(
            serialized.save()
        )
        return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

However, when I try to create a new user I am getting this error:

> Got a `TypeError` when calling `User.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `User.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the UserSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

This maybe because there's no password1 or password2 fields in the User model. But so, how can I create an API to create a new user using django-rest-framework?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think one password field is enough. If you want to check the user's twice password input is same, do it in the front-end. You can override a `create` method from serializer like following.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UserCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Comment: This is super helpful. This works even I don't have a custom user class and using the original user class