# Creat User by Api in django with rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

some problems with creating user in Django!!!!

Hello guys
I want to create user by Api in Django and i confused how to do that.
the first thing is should i logged in with superuser account and then create new user(or can i create anonymously? is that secure? )

The other questions is how to Authenticate anonymous user if anonymous person can create user.

Comment: what do you mean by 'create user by api'? where's your code for users to register? normally users sign up for your website by filling in a registration form (which creates the new user). Please be more specific in what issue you are facing exactly, write a [mcve].

Comment: i want use this api in my application(not on webpage)

Comment: This might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031323/how-to-create-a-new-user-with-django-rest-framework-and-custom-user-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django REST Framework provides a way to create users and authenticate them : 
For authentication refer: [Authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

For creating users you don't have to be logged-in as superuser , instead use **Django User Model** for creating new users

For any detailed advice , Please elaborate your question.

Comment: i want to create a user with username and profile image and phonenumber and etc and in user model we haven't these

Comment: Yeah!!! You can extend the model and create attributes for any other necessary fields