# How to create encrypted password in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Creating user using django rest framework, how to encrypt the user password.Need help with that.
here is my view

```
class UserCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):

def post(self, request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        User(
            serializer.save()
        )
        return Response({"status":"sucess", "code":status.HTTP_201_CREATED, "details":serializer.data})
    return Response({"status":"unsuccessful", "code":status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, "detsils":serializer.errors})
```

Comment: What do you mean to create encrypted password? Are you trying to create user and save the encrypted password in database? If yes, you should see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031323/how-to-create-a-new-user-with-django-rest-framework-and-custom-user-model. 
If you uses, Userserializer django will save your password with encryption, you needn't worry about that.

Comment: you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391122

Answer (score 2):

Django provides default password hashing technique using make_password method

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


print("your hashing password is  ", make_password(your password))
```

you can choose the different password hashing technique like md5,sha2,etc..

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'myproject.hashers.MyPBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)
```

configure your settings.py

Comment: I didn't use like this method, anyway thanks for your help